# PHP Splitting string using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to parse a formula structure that I have created.  So far It's really close.  I just need some help with the regex to split the equal sign out.

Here's the string I'm testing

```
({1+1=2|2+2=4}+{1+2=3|2+3=5})=16+10
```

This is the output i'm currently getting

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "("
  [1]=>
  string(13) "{1+1=2|2+2=4}"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "+"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "{1+2=3|2+3=5}"
  [4]=>
  string(1) ")"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "=16+10"
}
```

[EDIT] - Sorry forgot the expression.

```
$logical_test_parts = preg_split( "/({.+?})([\)|=|\+?])/" , $logical_test, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

the issue I'm having is on index 5.

I need index 5 to be `"="` and index 6 to be `16+10`

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What's your current regular expression, please?

Comment: Do you have to consider nested structures or escaped or quoted sequences?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the expression i was using, and yes nested structures could happen but I didn't know how to write such an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regex**: [`[()=]|\{[^\}]+\}|[+-]|[^=]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/qdY3uY/1)

By **@anubhava** you can reduce regex to: `{[^}]+}|[()=+-]|[^=()]+`

**Details**:

- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `[^]` Match a single character NOT present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the string
- `|` Or

**PHP code**:

```
$text = '({1+1=2|2+2=4}+{1+2=3|2+3=5})=16+10';
preg_match_all("/[()=]|\\{[^\}]+\\}|[+-]|[^=]+$/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (
    [1] => {1+1=2|2+2=4}
    [2] => +
    [3] => {1+2=3|2+3=5}
    [4] => )
    [5] => =
    [6] => 16+10
)
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/AAGDML29449)

Comment: Nice expression.

Comment: Not at all. Your expression seems to be better than mine :) [+1]

Comment: Very good answer ++ use `print_r($matches[0]);` to reduce one level of array

Comment: Also you can reduce this regex to: `/\{[^}]+}|[()=+-]|[^=()]+/`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  This regex works but I'm getting an issue on this string.  `[1+1=2?10/2:0]`. its dropping the 1's off so I am left with `+=2` when you implode the array.

Comment: @joeb The regex in this post works only for the pattern `({}+{})=n`, the rest you need to figure out for your self or write a new post describing problems that you have with regex attempts...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the equal signs removed, you should try this:

```
<?php

  $txt='({1+1=2|2+2=4}+{1+2=3|2+3=5})=16+10';

  $re1='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='(=)';   # Any Single Character 1
  $re3='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re4='(=)';   # Any Single Character 2
  $re5='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re6='(=)';   # Any Single Character 3
  $re7='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re8='(=)';   # Any Single Character 4
  $re9='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re10='(=)';  # Any Single Character 5

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8.$re9.$re10."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $c1=$matches[1][0];
      $c2=$matches[2][0];
      $c3=$matches[3][0];
      $c4=$matches[4][0];
      $c5=$matches[5][0];
      print "($c1) ($c2) ($c3) ($c4) ($c5) \n";
  }

?>
```

Quick and dirty way of dealing with it. The code has been generated by https://txt2re.com/. It's a really good tool for RegEx

Comment: I dont want the equals sign gone, I just want it separated from the formula to the right